# Can't see the alpha/texture of sculpting brush when changing size

Tags: sculpting

Very new to blender, so I don't even know what the name is for what I'm describing, or how to find the name, will attach pictures.

Basically, have been watching some tutorials for sculpting in blender, and notice that when the tutor adjusts their brush size, they can see the alpha(?)/texture projected into in the viewport.

Like this

[image]

But when I load up a new sculpt, I can't see the texture, it just looks like this.

[image]

Might the tutors have just uploaded a different texture prior to the tutorial, or is there some setting that I haven't found to make your alpha/texture visible?

Comment: you mean the dark area? if so, it's probably the brush strength (SHIFT + F)

Comment: I do, but I don't think that's the answer. Changing the brush strength changes the inner circle radius, but the dark area still doesn't appear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to enable the Falloff visibility in the Tool settings. You can access it in the header of the 3D view while sculpting or in the Tools properties in the properties editor.

[image]

Arguably the tooltip and the panel in which you access the overlay properties are misleading.

You can also change the opacity there. Enabling the Brush icon button will remove the overlay once you have clicked so it doesn't cover your mesh while sculpting.

Comment: Thank you! Do you also happen to know of a way to make a brush texture visible when resizing or rotating the brush? The brush texture is only visible when NOT adjusting size or rotation. Thanks

Comment: @Copperplate Unfortunately I think it is not possible. It would make sense though. Maybe worth adding a feature request on [RCS](https://blender.community/c/rightclickselect/?sorting=hot) if you're motivated

Comment: Ah, I see. Thanks for the info. For now, I guess using the "Stencil" feature comes the closest to this. Indeed, it would be a great feature to have. :-)